# Bezeichnung für die direkte Anrede in der dritten Person

Tags: grammar, salutation

Seit 2007 läuft im ORF die Talkshow »Wir sind Kaiser« (seit 2010 nur mehr vierteljährlich), in welcher der Talkmaster Robert Palfrader in der Rolle des »Kaiser Robert Heinrich I« prominente Gäste zur Audienz bittet. Er besteht dabei darauf, von allen Anwesenden im *Pluralis Majestatis* angesprochen zu werden (was aber vielen Talkgästen - zum Gaudium des Volkes, das den Audienzen beiwohnen darf - nur mangelhaft gelingt).

Umgekehrt spricht der Kaiser aber auch niemanden in der zweiten Person an. Er benutzt also weder »Du« noch »Sie« (in der 2. Person), sondern er redet sowohl alle Gäste als auch seine Dienstboten ausschließlich in der dritten Person an. Auch das irritiert viele Gäste.

Zum Beispiel die immer gleiche Floskel, mit der er jede Audienz zu beenden pflegt, und die direkt an den Gast gerichtet ist:

> Zu männlichen Gästen: »**Er** darf sich zurückziehen, aber **er** muss auch einmal ein bisserl brav sein!«
>   Zu weiblichen Gästen: »**Sie** darf sich zurückziehen, aber **sie** muss auch einmal ein bisserl brav sein!«

Gibt es für diese spezielle, veraltete Form der direkten Ansprache in der dritten Person eine bestimmte Bezeichnung, vergleichbar mit »Pluralis Majestatis« als Bezeichnung für die Ansprache einer einzelnen hochrangigen Person im Plural?

Comment: Nur neugierdehalber: Was bedeutet hier "im Pluralis Majestatis angesprochen zu werden"?
Die normale Anredeform im Deutschen *ist* die 3. Pers. *Pl.*
(*Haben Sie ...?*). Meinst Du die 3. Pers. Pl. mit Titel
(*Haben Eure Majestät ...?*), die 2. Pers. Pl. (*Habt Ihr ...?*), oder, was sehr merkwürdig wäre, die
1. Pers. Pl. (*Haben Wir ...?*)?

Comment: @Uwe: Anrede in der zweiten Person Plural (»Habt Ihr«). Ein paar Zitate: Sarah Conner zum Kaiser: »Ich will nicht, das **Ihr** mir den Rücken auch noch ableckt«. Ina Müller zum Kaiser: »Wenn **Ihr** sprecht, muss ich aufpassen« Wigald Boning: »War das nur eine Stunde Vorbereitung, die Sie genoss...« *verbessert sich* »die **Ihr** genossen habt« Der Kaiser sagt selbst übrigens auch nicht »ich« sondern ebenfalls »wir« (»Das haben wir uns schon gedacht«) (Daher auch der Titel der Sendung: »Wir sind Kaiser«) Siehe auch Wikipedia: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluralis_Majestatis

Comment: @Uwe: Er kann sich selbst ein Bild machen (ich habe mal ein paar Gäste aus Deutschland rausgesucht): Michael Bully Herwig beim Kaiser: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xBKelHTTkEQ Ina Müller beim Kaiser: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Aba7JnBwEAY Sarah Conner beim Kaiser: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=keFBEYM3u0M Wigald Boning beim Kaiser: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UE__jgfz-8g Jürgen Drews beim Kaiser: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oI8KsFt3xKk

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Als Analogon zum *Siezen* und *Duzen* gibt es *Erzen*, so erscheint es in der Wikipedia: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pronominale_Anredeform#Er, ansonsten einfach *Er-Anrede*.
Erscheint die Anrede als Anweisung mit Konjunktiv I, handelt es sich grammatikalisch um einen *Jussiv*:

> Er ziehe sich zurück und sei mal ein bisserl brav.

Comment: Findet Er es nicht unangemessen, ein Wort als „neumodisch“ abzuqualifizieren, das schon mindestens seit dem 19. Jahrhundert belegt ist? Werfe Er doch einmal [einen Blick in den Grimm](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?bookref=3,1086,1), falls Er es nicht glaubt, und nehme Er sich die Kritik gegen die seinerzeit Neumodischen zu Herzen, die _eren_ statt _erzen_ sagten.

Comment: Danke, ich habe es korrigiert. Ich hatte im Duden nachgesehen, da steht es gar nicht drin (bzw. bedeutet *ehern*).

Comment: Das hat er schön beantwortet! ^_^

Comment: Nach der Lektüre der Kommentare tut sich gleich die nächste Frage auf: Schreibt man das Anredepronomen »er« groß oder klein? Im verlinkten Wikipedia-Artikel wird das Anrede-Er auch groß geschrieben, das Andere-Wir hingegen klein. Bei der Erläuterung des Berliner-Er wird »er« aber klein geschrieben. Gibt es dafür eine verbindliche Grundlage? Ich würde das alles kleinschreiben.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Heute wird es analog zum Sie oder Du groß geschrieben, wobei diese Pronomen mittlerweile meiner Erinnerung nach auch generell kleingeschrieben werden dürfen.