# Groß- oder Kleinschreibung von »er/Er« in der direkten Anrede

Tags: pronoun, capitalization

In Antworten und Kommentaren zur Frage über die [Bezeichnung für die direkte Anrede in der dritten Person](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/27547/1487) wurden Beispiele gepostet, in denen das Anredepronomen *er/Er* großgeschrieben wurde. Ich möchte nun wissen, ob diese Schreibweise korrekt ist, bzw. ob es dafür überhaupt offizielle Regeln gibt.

Als Ausgangspunkt fasse ich die diesbezüglichen Regeln zusammen, die ich finden konnte:

- Pronomen werden generell kleingeschrieben. Ausnahmen gibt es nur für Anrede- und davon abgeleitete Possessivpronomen. Die folgenden Punkte beziehen sich ausschließlich auf diese potentiellen Ausnahmen. (Insbesondere ist »sie« als Personalpronomen der dritten Person immer kleinzuschreiben, weil Personalpronomen nicht zu den potentiellen Ausnahmefällen gehören)
- Wenn ein bestimmtes Pronomen großzuschreiben ist, gilt das auch für all seine Deklinationsformen. Wenn daher im Folgenden die Form im Singular Nominativ behandelt wird, gilt alles gesagt ebenfalls für den Plural und für alle anderen Fälle.
- Vor 1998 waren für *Du* und *Sie* immer die Großschreibung vorgesehen. (Ob das auch schon vor 1901 so war, habe ich nicht eruieren können)
- Zwischen 1998 und 2006 musste *du* immer kleingeschrieben werden (*Sie* blieb weiterhin zwingend groß).
- Seit 2006 kommt es auf die Textsorte an, ob *du/Du* groß- oder kleinzuschreiben ist: In Briefen und ähnlichen Textsorten kann man sich aussuchen, ob man *du* oder *Du* schreibt (muss innerhalb eines Dokuments aber bei der einmal gewählten Schreibweise bleiben). In anderen Textsorten kann man nicht wählen, hier muss *du* immer kleingeschrieben werden. *Sie* muss weiterhin immer großgeschrieben werden.

Leider beantwortet keine dieser Regeln die Frage, ob *er/Er* und *sie/Sie*, wenn sie als Anredepronomen verändert werden, groß- oder kleinzuschreiben sind.

Gemeint ist das Anredepronomen im folgenden Beispiel:

> Kaiser zum Bittsteller: »Nun sag’ **er/Er** schon, was **er/Er** von uns will.«

Comment: Randbemerkung: „Vor 1998 waren für _Du_ und _Sie_ immer die Großschreibung vorgesehen.“ – Das stimmt nicht, für _du_ galt die gleiche Regel wie heute (Großschreibung in Briefen o.ä. erlaubt, sonst nicht). **R 71** aus der 20. Auflage des Rechtschreibdudens: „Das Anredepronomen in Briefen wird groß geschrieben. … Bei der Wiedergabe von Reden, Dialogen u.ä. … wird jedoch *klein* geschrieben.“ – Außerdem trat der erste Anlauf zur Rechtschreibreform 1996 in Kraft, meines Wissens auch in Österreich.

Comment: Korrektur: Nicht die gleiche Regel, sondern Großschreibung in Briefen war zwingend vorgegeben.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Der Fall ist in der [*Amtlichen Regelung*](http://rechtschreibrat.ids-mannheim.de/download/regeln2006.pdf) ausdrücklich behandelt, und zwar in § 65 E1 (gleichlautend in den Fassungen von 1996 und 2006):

> Großschreibung gilt auch für ältere Anredeformen wie: *Habt Ihr es Euch überlegt, Fürst von Gallenstein? Johann, führe Er die Gäste herein.*

Auch vor 1996 galt dasselbe; in der 20. Auflage des Rechtschreibdudens werden folgende Beispielsätze zu R 72 angeführt:

> Schweig’ Er! Höre Sie mir gut zu!

Daher ist in jedem Fall für *Er* diese Schreibung richtig:

> Nun sag’ Er schon, was Er von Uns will.

Nicht ganz klar ist, wie *Uns* als Majestätsplural nach neuer Rechtschreibung zu behandeln ist; dazu scheint es keine Regel zu geben. Nach alter Rechtschreibung galt Großschreibung (Rechtschreibduden, 20. Auflage, Wörterteil), und auch die heutige Onlineausgabe des Dudens [geht von Großschreibung aus](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/wir#Bedeutung2b).

Comment: Interessant dass in allen Fällen die Wiedergabe von mündlicher Sprache vorliegt, "du" also kleingeschrieben würde. Die Frage, *warum* Er, Ihr usw. dann großgeschrieben werden sollen, ginge wohl zu weit ...

Comment: @Raketenolli: Aus demselben Grund wie bei der Anrede _Sie_, nämlich weil es eine eigentlich unpassende Form ist.

Answer (score 6):

Laut [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Er_Anrede) wird das als veraltete Anrede an eine männliche Person gebrauchte Pronomen „Er“ großgeschrieben.

> höre Er!

Eine Regel hierzu wird im Duden nicht genannt; allerdings wird dieser Fall tatsächlich im amtlichen Regelwerk zur deutschen Rechtschreibung erwähnt, und zwar als Ergänzung zu § 65 (über Anwendung von Groß- oder Kleinschreibung bei Anredepronomen und Anreden):

> E1: Großschreibung gilt auch für ältere Anredeformen wie: *Habt Ihr es Euch überlegt, Fürst von Gallenstein? Johann, führe Er die Gäste herein.*